# Please Send QFont Alternative Class To Generate PDF

Tags: qt4, qcoreapplication

`Unhandled exception at 0x6523c5ec (QtGuid4.dll) in PdfGen.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.`

I am getting  above error for  `QFont` with `QCoreapplication` . any alternatives for qfont to generate pdf

Comment: Looks like a NULL pointer dereference. Can you show the code where this is occurring?